# How to open multiple modals with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on 'send message' button multiple modals open, what I want is only one modal opens.

So my question is: How to open the first element of multiple bootstrap modals with the same class?

My html code:

```
<!-- button -->                                                    
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default tooltiped" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Send a message" style="min-width:65px;" onclick="message_modal(46)"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Message</button>
</div>    

<!-- message Modal -->
<div class="modal fade message-modal-46"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header message-modal-header"> 
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4>Send message to ferair</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body message-body">
        <div class="alert-notify-modal"></div>
        <form class="orb-form">
          <section>
            <label class="label"><strong>Votre message</strong></label>
            <label class="textarea">
            <textarea class="message-content-form" rows="3" placeholder="Write your message here" name"message-content-form"></textarea>
            </label>
           </section>
         </form>
       </div>

       <div class="data-thread-id hidden" data-thread-id="43"></div>
       <div class="data-receiver-id hidden" data-receiver-id="46"></div>

       <div class="modal-footer message-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary modal-message-submit-btn">send</button>
       </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->                          
<!--/ Message Modal -->
```

JQUERY:

```
var session_user_id = 1;

//Open message modal
function message_modal(type_id){

   //If not loggedin redirect to login page
   if(!session_user_id){

      window.location.href = base_url+"users/login";
      return;
   }

   //We refresh the div to show message modal 
   $(".message-modal-"+type_id).load(location.href+" .message-modal-"+type_id+">*", function () {

     $(".message-modal-"+type_id).modal('show');

   });
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/neu17vzh/)

Comment: With jQuery you can select the first matched element using eq(0) (0 because the array of matched elements is 0 indexed). to get the DOM element use .get(0). https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: @Michael Beeson  hi thanks for ur reply... I tried your suggestion but didn't work.

Comment: It does work. Just add .eq(0) immediately before the .load() function and also before the .show() function

Comment: @MichaelBeeson I tried that too but this is what I get https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3676646/5e0b642f0eb27cd782c1f49ac9b7e949

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with jsFiddle. It seems that problem happens when you first load the page, but then if you click "run" it behaves as expected. What happens if you just try running this code on a server?

Comment: @MichaelBeeson In jsfiddle it's working good but on my localhost it displays all modals with same class

Answer (score 0):

There are a few typos in your code, which cause the issue you're running into.

First, this line: `<h4>Send message to ferair</strong></h4>`. You are closing a strong tag, but you never opened one. This is true for both modals.

Secondly, this line: `<textarea class="message-content-form" rows="3" placeholder="Write your message here" name"message-content-form"></textarea>` The name you give does not have a `=` sign after it. Again this is an issue on both modals.

Lastly, you use the same ID for both modals. Because of this, both match and are activated. If you use unique IDs, [your code works perfectly](https://jsfiddle.net/Bronzdragon/neu17vzh/4/).

Edit: I mis-read the question, you wish to keep the classes unchanged. You can select the first result of a JQuery selection with the .first() function. If you [update your Javascript to this](https://jsfiddle.net/Bronzdragon/neu17vzh/10/), it'll work:

```
var session_user_id = 1;

//Open message modal
function message_modal(type_id){
  //If not loggedin redirect to login page
  if(!session_user_id){
    window.location.href = base_url+"users/login";
    return;
  }

  //We refresh the div to show message modal 
  $(".message-modal-"+type_id).first().load(location.href+" .message-modal-"+type_id+">*", function () {
    $(".message-modal-"+type_id).first().modal('show');
  });
}
```